# Make gameobject unselectable in the Editor window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a fadepanel `gameobject` in my scene that has to sit on top of all the other gameobjects. However, when I click on an object int the editor window, since this `gameobject` is on top of all, is the one that is automatically selected in the hierarchy.

Is there a way to keep the `gameobject` on top of the canvas, as it is right now, but make it completely unselectable wIen i click on my scene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `HideFlags` on `gameobject` to make it unselectable:

```
public class HideFlagsSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Component target;
    public HideFlags customHideFlags;

    public enum Mode
    {
        GameObject,
        Component
    }

    public Mode setOn = Mode.GameObject;

    [ContextMenu("Set Flags")]
    private void SetFlags()
    {
        if (setOn == Mode.GameObject)
        {
            target.gameObject.hideFlags = customHideFlags;
        }
        else if (setOn == Mode.Component)
        {
            target.hideFlags = customHideFlags;
        }
    }
}
```

Setting customHideFlags to `HideInHierarchy` would make it disappear from hierarchy so you won't be able to select it.

**Edit:** As the object will disappear, there is no way to bring it back if you can't access the script. So this script should be attached to a persistent object and target object should be set in the inspector.

You can use Context menu option by clicking on the gear icon in the top right corner and choose "Set Flags". its the last option in the menu.

[Read more](http://nielson.io/2015/10/controlling-object-visibility-and-editability-in-unity-using-hideflags/)

---

Hope this helps :)

(ADDED BY PERSON WHO ASKED THE QUESTION)

I wanted a way for this to automagically happen on editor mode. So i did the same steps, but i changed the script a bit to work on Editor mode. I added [ExecuteInEditMode] on top of the class and also added an Awake() method that executes the same code as in SetFlags. Seems to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Umair ! I have tried that and it does work, but it reverts back to the previous state once I play the game and stop it. The object hides from the hierarchy when i do it manually but it does not persist to be hidden once i play the game :( Are you getting the same behavior ?

Comment: Hmm, it may require ExecuteInEditMode to work automatically maybe based on the article. I'll test that.

Comment: Yeah, I made it work on editor mode automatically. Will append in the end of your post if that's ok for reference